# Where does Xamarin store your app keystore by default?

Tags: xamarin, google-play, keystore

I wrote an app about 3 years ago using Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin.  I generated my signing key and published my app to google play.  I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin and am trying to find the keystore that contains the key needed for me to publish a release build to the Google Play store, but can't find it.

Can anyone suggest some directories that I should check?  Should I ask Google to reset my app keys?

Comment: Did you Search in file explorer by using keyword "keystore" or "jks" ?

Answer (score 1):

You used the debug keystore to sign your App with? That is not a good thing. It will be here though: `C:\Users\Cheesebaron\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android` replace Cheesebaron with your username.

If you created a KeyStore to sign Apps for Google Store using the Archive tool in Visual Studio it should be there and look something like this:

[image]

The Keystore folder will contain any keystores you have created with the Archive tool.

If you can't find your keystore, you would have to get your keys reset and create a new one, which you store a *safe* place.